# "Module not found: Can't resolve" in React

Tags: reactjs

I've got a react project in a folder 'react-test' and inside are all of the json and node modules etc and the src folder installed by running create-react-app.

Inside the src folder I've got `App.js` and a components folder with `Titles.js` inside.

I want to import a class named `Titles` from `Titles.js`.

I'm using the relative file path `./components/Titles.js` but I get the following error when I do:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Titles.js' in '/Users/username/Documents/ReactApp1/react-test/src'
```

This is my Titles.js component:

```
import React from "react";
class Titles extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Weather Finder</h1>
        <p>Find out temperature, conditions, and more...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Titles;
```

This is my App.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Titles from "./components/Titles.js";

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Titles />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've been trying to mess with the file path in the import statement but nothing has worked so far. Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Is this the folder structure you have?](https://codesandbox.io/s/r7zz6r5xmo) It should work nicely.

Comment: Posting your (text version) actual directory structure (like from a `tree` command, obviously skipping `node_modules`) would be helpful; we can't see what you *actually* have, only what you *say* you have. Not that we don't trust you, but import/export issues like this are usually down to exactly that--directory structure issues.

Comment: How do you run your app?

Comment: Thanks it was a problem with my file structure. Sorry for the total newbie question and thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put in your Titles.js file at the end of your code :

export default (the name of your component)